# UICollectionView - item insert animation similar to Viber chat conversation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viber

I want to implement an animated insert as in viber chat when adding a new message, [video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9P1Atz-2S0)

My code does something similar, but does not quite look like, I want to make an exact copy of the animation that viber has

```swift
override open func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)

    attributes?.alpha = 0.0
    attributes?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)    
    return attributes
}
```

and insertion :

```swift
messageList.append(message)
messagesCollectionView.insertSections([messageList.count - 1])
messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom()
```